# ValidationError when posting JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, validationerror

I have this schema for authors:

```
module.exports = {
  "id": "Author",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The full name of the author"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "A small bio of the author"
    },
    "books": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "The list of books published on at least one of the stores by this author",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "Book"
      }
    },
    "website": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The website url of the author"
    },
    "avatar": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The url of the avatar of this author"
    }
  }
}
```

When I POST to http://localhost:9000/authors/ to create a new author I get this error:

> error: Error of type InternalServerError found: ValidationError: books: Cast to Array failed for value "[ 'The Twits', 'The BFG' ]" at path "books"

This is the JSON I'm posting

```
{
    "name": "Roald Dahl",
    "description": "Writes childrens novels",
    "books": [
        "The Twits",
        "The BFG"
    ],
    "website": "www.roalddahl.com",
    "avatar": "https://www.natgeokids.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Roald-Dahl-1-1.jpg"
}
```

To the best of my knowledge this JSON is correct. The error seems to suggest there is an issue with the `books` array. Is this the case and if so, how do I fix it?

Adding Book schema:

```
module.exports = {
  "id": "Book",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "descrtiption": "The title of the book"
    },
    "authors": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "List of authors of the book",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "Author"
      }
    },
    "isbn_code": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The stores where clients can buy this book"
    },
    "stores": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "The stores where clients can buy this book",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "store": {
            "$ref": "Store"
          },
          "copies": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "genre": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Genre of the book",
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Description of the book"
    },
    "reviews": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "ClientReview"
      }
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "description": "The price of this book"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `"items": { "$ref": "Book" }` mean? I use [this](https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/) online tool to test and without that, data is valid!

Comment: `$ref` is perfectly fine in a JSON schema; assuming there is a schema for a `Book` object then the ref (as used by the OP here) would mean that the array would contain Book objects. But in the JSON document, the OP is using strings, not book objects.

Comment: I added the `Book` schema for visibility. This code is from the book "REST API Development With Node.js". I'm learning it so there are a few things I'm not sure about(e.g. `$ref`). With that in mind My JSON is probably incorrectly using string for the books. Assuming it should use a book object how would I change my JSON to use this? Do I need to add the books first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting JSON with the `books` field as an array of strings, so your validator object should specify:

```
items: { type: "string" },
```